# Auto-increment in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, increment

I need to populate several columns of MYSQL table with data from arrays. So one column corresponds to one array. I have used the following code to fill just one column with data:

```
function addSystemDataTanks ($db, $tankNamesArray, $tankVolumesArray) {
    $myArray = array(); 
    $myString = implode ("'), ('",$myArray);
    $statement = "replace into myTable (ID, NAME)";
    $statement .= "values (' ";
    $statement .= $myString;
    $statement .= "')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $statement);

    if ($result) {
       return true;
    }
}
```

I need the ID field to be populated by auto-generated incremented numbers. But I need these rows to be replaced with new values next time this form is submitted. For the "replace" to work the ID has to be the same as previously used, otherwise it will just create new entries. 
Also, is there a better way to input arrays as columns in MYSQL table, other than one by one, cause I need all row values to match to each other and the ID should be unique and start from 0 or 1 next time the form is submitted.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the structure of the table `myTable`? Is `NAME` to be unique? If yes then the problem is simple - if not then to UPDATE on the next form submission you would need to include the ID somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the row ID to be incremental you're making life hard for yourself! When you create the table in MySQL, use AUTO_INCREMENT on the ID, then you can just enter a NULL value for the ID in your code:

```
CREATE TABLE blah (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(ID));

$sql = "INSERT INTO blah VALUES(NULL, 'Adam')";
```

"Adam" will now have an ID of 1 :)

Comment: Using the `INSERT` query you provided - `id` won't be 0. It will be the first possible auto_increment value, most likely 1. The other part of the problem with your answer is that the `CREATE TABLE` statement won't execute -  issue is `INT(500)` (wtf really). I won't downvote you but consider improving the answer.

Comment: Meant to write 1, not zero haha. And with the INT(500) - Seriously, wtf myself. I have no idea why I typed that.

Comment: Must be one of those days.. it happens :)